# How do I access a LISTAGG that is used in sub query?

Tags: oracle, subquery, listagg

I have the query below, I am trying to select **inner_query.ship_codes**.

If I do **inner_query.item_id_alias** it works fine, but how can I select the **ship_codes** from my inner_query ?

```sql
SELECT inner_query.item_id_alias
FROM (
  SELECT li.item_id as item_id_alias,
         LISTAGG(a.ship_code, '; ')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.ship_code) as "ship_codes"
  FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                ship_code, 
                MAX(order_id) as order_id
         FROM   orders o
         WHERE  o.order_id in (
                  SELECT li2.order_id
                  FROM   line_items li2 
                  GROUP BY li2.order_id
                ) 
         GROUP BY ship_code
       )a
       INNER JOIN line_items li ON a.order_id = li.order_id      
  GROUP BY li.item_id
) inner_query;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the column alias. Since you have used a quoted identifier in the sub-query then you need to use the quoted identifier in the outer query (and anywhere else you may want to reference it):

```sql
SELECT inner_query.item_id_alias,
       inner_query."ship_codes"
FROM (
  SELECT li.item_id as item_id_alias,
         LISTAGG(a.ship_code, '; ')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.ship_code) as "ship_codes"
  FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                ship_code, 
                MAX(order_id) as order_id
         FROM   orders o
         WHERE  o.order_id in (
                  SELECT li2.order_id
                  FROM   line_items li2 
                  GROUP BY li2.order_id
                ) 
         GROUP BY ship_code
       )a
       INNER JOIN line_items li ON a.order_id = li.order_id      
  GROUP BY li.item_id
) inner_query;
```

Alternatively, you can use a wildcard:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (...) inner_query
```

or a wildcard with the alias for the sub-query:

```
SELECT inner_query.*
FROM   (...) inner_query
```

or the identifiers without the alias for the sub-query:

```
SELECT item_id_alias,
       "ship_codes"
FROM   (...) inner_query
```

*(Note: using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same `SELECT` statement is pointless. You can remove the `DISTINCT` and the output will not change.)*

Comment: Thank you so much ! 
Can't believe I did not see that. 

Also thank you for the extra tip on removing DISTINCT !